# Any idea what happened to this door and advice on how to paint it?

Tags: painting, metal, primer

How would you paint this metal door and metal window jamb/trim? I have no idea what was done to the door!

Here are photos of the door:
[image]
[image]
[image]

And of the window jamb:
[image]
[image]

Gallery link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBNC8.jpg

Some notes:

1. Magnets stick to both the door and window jamb, so I guess it is steel
2. The front/trim part of the window jamb is really smooth to touch. The inner/reveal part is slightly rougher but still I would call it smooth. The door is rough.

My rough plan so far:

1. Scrape/sand/clean
2. Prime with oil-based primer and paint with whatever type of paint works best with the primer

However I'm stuck figuring out what sort of primer to use mainly because I'm not sure how to determine if the steel is galvanized or not? Can anyone guess from the photos what I'm dealing with here? Thanks!

**EDIT:** I should have mentioned that I'd like to DIY it and to do it in-place, without removing the door or windows. I don't mind if it doesn't look great, just trying to get it to look better than it currently does!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like rust.  The remarkable thing about it is how well matched the brown paint is to the rust.

Vanilla advice would be to grind it all down to clean bare metal, quickly prime it and repaint.  Hopefully you can remove this door and do the work outside.  Do it in place and you'll have permanent rust stains on every surface of the room, and will have to prime and double coat all the walls and ceilings.

But this looks like the interior of an apartment door.  I think what I would do first is ask why an interior apartment door has become so rusty.  The answer might lead you to take different approaches to this.

Answer (score 0):

On advice from Reddit https://www.reddit.com/r/HomeImprovement/comments/rls6nl/any_idea_what_happened_to_this_door_and_advice_on/ and my local Sherwin Williams store, I went with a Latex Primer and Paint.

The downside of oil-based primer if this steel turns out to be galvanized is that the primer will react with the zinc and not stick. The upside of the oil-based primer is that, if this steel's **not** galvanized, oil will last longer than latex primer.

I'm not sure how to remove any doubt that it's galvanized so I decided on latex.

Answer (score 0):

Galvanise is a silver-blue often crystaline looking surface finish. there'as no sign of that.

It looks like rusty steel.

scrape/wirebrush/sand smooth-ish then apply red-oxide primer or other anti-rust primer.

You can then paint as normal.